# Event handler not firing in WebForms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, event-handling

i have a page which dynanically create a link when it load, after i click on the link it should loop in the database fetch all the record and display another set of link , then when i click on these link it should give me all information about this particular record it like this one

**Q:** when the page loads, it creates the first link which is associated with an event handler, it fire the first event handler (Getname) but it not firing the second event handler (GetnameDetails)

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

        If ViewState.Item("nameload") IsNot Nothing Then
            If ViewState.Item("nameload").ToString = "True" Then
                Getname(Me, New EventArgs)
            ElseIf ViewState.Item("Getnameload").ToString = "True" Then
                GetnameDetails(Me, New EventArgs)
            Else
                CreateNamesButton()
            End If
        Else
            CreateNamesButton()
        End If
```

---

page load and name link create

```
Private Sub CreateNamesButton()
        Dim btnName As New LinkButton
        btnName .Text = "Name"
        Panel1.Controls.Add(btnName)
        AddHandler btnName .Click, AddressOf Getname
        ViewState.Item("nameload") = False.ToString
    End Sub
```

---

it fire nameload event handler

```
Private Sub Getname(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' get products list here
        ' and set handlers for each link

        Dim testDb As New customer
        Dim arr As ArrayList = testDb.DbLoop()
        Dim ObjCustList As CustomerBo
        Dim CustInt As Integer
        Dim str As String

        Dim link As LinkButton

        For Each ObjCustList In arr
            CustInt = ObjCustList.Cus_Id
            link = New LinkButton
            Panel1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
            link.ID = CustInt
            link.Text = ObjCustList.FirstName
            link.CommandArgument = CustInt
            str = link.CommandArgument
            AddHandler link.Click, AddressOf GetnameDetails
            Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(link)

        Next ObjCustList

        ViewState.Item("nameload") = True.ToString

    End Sub
```

---

it not fire

```
Private Sub GetnameDetails(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim getRecord As New CustomerBo
        Dim lbLink As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)
        Dim CustomerID As String = lbLink.CommandArgument
        Dim getLink As String = lbLink.Text
        Dim SendCustID As Integer
        SendCustID = CInt(CustomerID)
        getRecord.Cus_Id = SendCustID

        Dim getAllcatInfo As New customer
        getRecord = getAllcatInfo.R_List(getRecord)
        Panel1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<table><tr>"))
        Panel1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<td colspan=2 align=center    valign=middle >"))
        Panel1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(getRecord.FirstName))
        Panel1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</td>"))
        Panel1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<td>"))
        Panel1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(getRecord.LastName))
        Panel1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</td>"))
        Panel1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<td>"))
        Panel1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(getRecord.Telephone))
        Panel1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</td></tr></table>"))
        ViewState.Item("Getnameload") = True.ToString

        'get product details here
    End Sub
```

what am doing wrong thank

Answer (score 1):

Its because your else condition is not executed, read my comments within the code.

```
 If ViewState.Item("nameload").ToString = "True" Then  // this is true
        Getname(Me, New EventArgs) // Executed
    ElseIf ViewState.Item("Getnameload").ToString = "True" Then // this is not executed and not attached to the handler
        GetnameDetails(Me, New EventArgs) // not executed
    Else
```